Python append a dictionary to an already existing one, within in a loop
I have created a Python script (3.9+) to extract some data from an API query result, and to write what I want into a dictionary, and this query needs to iterate through all pages (it can only be done by pagin every 100 elements).
I have the loop working but the problem is that the dictionat is overwritten on every iteration, no matter if I use 'dict.update()' or 'dict |= (append function)'.
This is my current code:
i = 1 
while True:
    api_url = '{0}networkdevice?size=100&page={1}'.format(ise_url,i)

    response = requests.request("GET", api_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    search_key = 'resources'
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        devices = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        for value in devices:
            for k,v in devices[value].items():
                if i == 1 and k == 'total':
                    counter = int(''.join(map(str, [int(v) for k, v in devices[value].items() if 'total' in k])))
                    pages = counter // 100
                    resto = counter % 100
                    res = dict(filter(lambda item: search_key in item[0], devices[value].items()))
                elif i > 1:
                    # res.update(dict(filter(lambda item: search_key in item[0], devices[value].items())))      #==> NOT WORKING
                    res |= dict(filter(lambda item: search_key in item[0], devices[value].items()))             #==>NOT WORKING

    i += 1
    print("Page: " + str(i))
    if resto > 0:
        if i > pages+1:
            break

for j in res['resources']:
    print(j['id'] + "\t" + j['name'])


the issue is that you're reassigning the res dictionary on each iteration, which causes it to overwrite the previous data. Instead, you should initialize res outside the loop and then append the new data to it on each iteration.

I have initialized RES outside the loop, and then changed the line inside loop from "res = dict" to "res |= dict" and that is not making any difference.
Added line above the while loop: "res = {}"

If this is from any help, this is how the "res" dictionary looks like:
{'resources': [{'id': '1111', 'name': 'name1', 'description': '', 'link': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https:url.com/1111', 'type': 'application/json'}}, {'id': '2222', 'name': 'name2', 'description': '', 'link': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https:url.com/2222', 'type': 'application/json'}}]}

And this is the complete output before p`rocessing it to extract "id" and "name":
{'SearchResult': {'total': 419, 'resources': [{'id': '1111', 'name': 'name1', 'description': '', 'link': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https:url.com/111', 'type': 'application/json'}}, {'id': '2222', 'name': 'name2', 'description': '', 'link': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https:url.com/2222', 'type': 'application/json'}}], 'nextPage': {'rel': 'next', 'href': 'https:url.com?size=100&page=2', 'type': 'application/json'}}}

This is most likely due to how dict union works in python. Assuming you indeed put yours res declaration before your loop, res.update(something) (or res |= something) works as follow: for each entry in something : if it's not in res, put it in res, else overwrite res. You are consequently rewriting over your previous records.

For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including some example input data and minimal code (so, assuming the request/response is working correctly, put the data in the code itself) as well as expected output and actual output.

Like the below solution would be useful:
import requests
import json

ise_url = "your_ise_url_here"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer your_token_here"}
payload = {}

i = 1
res = {"resources": []}  # Initialize res outside the loop

while True:
  api_url = f'{ise_url}networkdevice?size=100&page={i}'
  response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, data=payload)

  if response.status_code == 200:
    devices = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    search_key = 'resources'

  if i == 1:
    counter = devices['total']
    pages = counter // 100
    resto = counter % 100

    res['resources'].extend(devices[search_key])  # Append new data to res['resources']

    i += 1
    print(f"Page: {i}")

  if resto > 0 and i > (pages + 1):
    break

for j in res['resources']:
  print(f"{j['id']}\t{j['name']}")

